# mostrar datos relacionado en formato JSON

Tags: php, json, tablas

la verdad este foro me a ayudado mucho, y quisiera saber si me pueden resolver esta inquietud, quiero mostrar datos relacionados en formato JSON. este es el codigo PHP que estoy utilizando.

```
$query = "SELECT E.nombre_produc, E.precio, D.fecha_compra FROM adicional_habitacion D INNER JOIN productos E ON D.id = E.id";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

if (!$resultado) {
    die("Error");
} else {
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        $arreglo["data"][] = $data;
    }
    echo json_encode($arreglo);
}

mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

pero no me muestra nada.
Estos datos de la imagen a continuación me debería de  mostrar.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me sale una pagina en blanco.
talvez esta mal la consulta:
`$query = "SELECT E.nombre_produc, E.precio, D.fecha_compra FROM adicional_habitacion D INNER JOIN productos E ON D.id = E.id";` 
y haya otro método para hacer lo quiero hacer pero siempre en `JSON`, y quisiera su ayuda y me den una solucion.

gracias de ante mano.

Comment: define el arreglo despues del resultado a ver ejemplo: `$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query); $arreglo = ["data"=>[]];`

Comment: gracias por responder, mira soy aun un poco nuevo en esto, pero siguiendo lo que me dijiste lo hice así, `$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
 $arreglo = ["data"=>[]];` pero me sigue arrojando una pagina en blanco.

Answer (score 1):

Wessly,
Su query está correcta. Para que devuelva resultados las tablas tiene que tener la estructura abajo:

1 - tabla adicional_habitacion

```
CREATE TABLE `adicional_habitacion` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_compra` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

2 - tabla productos

```
CREATE TABLE `productos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_produc` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `precio` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

3 - Consulta

```
SELECT E.ID,E.nombre_produc, E.precio, D.fecha_compra 
FROM adicional_habitacion D
INNER JOIN productos E ON D.id = E.id
```

[image: Resultado de la consulta]

Comment: Wessly, haga un cambio en esa parte del código:
$arreglo = array() // inicializa la varible

if (!$resultado) {
    die("Error");
} else {
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        $arreglo[] = $data; // linea cambianda
    }
    echo json_encode($arreglo);
}